# How can I create a list with the first column?

Tags: python

```
Available formats:
37  :   mp4 [1080x1920]
46  :   webm    [1080x1920]
22  :   mp4 [720x1280]
45  :   webm    [720x1280]
35  :   flv [480x854]
44  :   webm    [480x854]
34  :   flv [360x640]
18  :   mp4 [360x640]
43  :   webm    [360x640]
5   :   flv [240x400]
17  :   mp4 [144x176]
```

That's the output of `youtube-dl -F url`. I'm writing a script and I need to check if the video has the format 18.

How can I extract that first column on a list? Then it is easy to check.

Comment: What is the content-type, simple text? or JSON? or XML? Anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this, considering the data is stored in a text file:

```
In [15]: with open("abc") as f:
   ....:     for line in f:
   ....:         spl=line.split()
   ....:         if '18' in spl:
   ....:             print line
   ....:             break
   ....:             
18  :   mp4 [360x640]
```

or if the data is stored in a string:

```
In [16]: strs="""Available formats:
   ....:     37  :   mp4 [1080x1920]
   ....:     46  :   webm    [1080x1920]
   ....:     22  :   mp4 [720x1280]
   ....:     45  :   webm    [720x1280]
   ....:     35  :   flv [480x854]
   ....:     44  :   webm    [480x854]
   ....:     34  :   flv [360x640]
   ....:     18  :   mp4 [360x640]
   ....:     43  :   webm    [360x640]
   ....:     5   :   flv [240x400]
   ....:     17  :   mp4 [144x176]"""
   ....:     

In [17]: for line in strs.splitlines():
   ....:     spl=line.split()
   ....:     if '18' in  spl:
   ....:         print line
   ....:         break
   ....:         
    18  :   mp4 [360x640]
```

Comment: Mmm I hadn't thought on write the output to a file. On this way, of course it is easy. I give you the accepted answer because you were the first.

Answer (score 0):

If this is simple list, do as follows:

1. Read one line at a time as a string
2. Split the string on colon :
3. Trim the 1st item
4. Parse the item as a number

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to know if a certain format exists, you just need to check if a line starts with '18 ':

```
format_exisits = False

for line in input_file:
    if line.startswith('18 '):
        format_exisits = True
        break

print(format_exists)
```

Answer (score 0):

use subprocess to get the output from python and split/strip as you wish.

```
import subprocess

cmd = ["youtube-dl" "-F" "url"]

output = subprocess.check_output(cmd)

formats = {format[0].strip():format[1].strip() for format in [format.split(":") for format in output.split("\n")[1:]]}

"17" in formats
```